# Principle of induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

What is the statement of the second principle of mathematical induction?

My teacher gave me this:

Let $X$ be a non-empty subset of $\mathbb{N}$ with the property that given $m \in \mathbb{N}$, if every $ n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $n <m$ belongs to $X$ then $m$ belongs to $X$, then $X= \mathbb{N}$.

In Internet I have found that they put as condition that 1 this in $X$, I do not know if they are equivalent ... or not.

Comment: Yes you need to assume $1\in X$.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't have to explicitly put $1$ in $X$. With the condition as stated you would put $1$ in $X$ if and only if all natural numbers smaller than $1$ are in $X$. Well, there are no natural numbers smaller than $1$ (this is all assuming $0 \not \in \mathbb{N}$ by the way), and so it *is* true that *all* (zero) natural numbers smaller than $1$ are in $X$. Therefore, if $X$ has the property as stated, $1$ is automatically in $X$.

Answer (score 0):

On second thought, the statement in your post is correct. Why? Well, we only need to see that it implies $1 \in X$.

So let $m  = 1$. Then there is no $n < m, n \in \mathbb N$. Hence the condition of the stated implication is true ("$\forall n < m \colon n \in X$" is true) because there is no $n < m$. Thus the conclusion must be true, i.e. $1 \in X$.

Comment: But  in my definition $m$ is arbitrary ... so for example $ 3 \in \mathbb{N}$ ,$2<3 \in X$ but $1<3$ no belongs to $X$. In your example $X$ no satisfies the statement...

Comment: Sorry, I fixed my answer.

Comment: Oh!, thanks I clear the problem :D